# explain this css behavior of absolute position

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

i want to know if this behavior in css is normal and why?
my question is about position: absolute; 
i have two divs , the first of them contain image when positioned it in absolute position with 0 bottom and right 0 it stick in the end of the page( but not the end of the real page but the end of the page displayed view )
note that it doesn't have any parent with absolute or fixed or relative position

### [JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/lucoxofaqe/edit?html,output)

[image: the image to the result]
this is a full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        body {
            background: #808080;
            /*height:1200px;*/
        }

        .content {
            background: rgba(0, 148, 255, 0.69);
            /*min-height:400px;*/
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border: 6px groove #00ff90;
        }


        h1 {
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
            right: 5px;
        }

        p {
            /*position: relative;*/
            /*top: 150px;*/
            /*right: 5px;*/
        }


        img {
            border: 3px groove #0ff;
            width: 400px;
            position: absolute;
            /*top:0px;
    right:0px;*/
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>why we should using reletive posittios</h1>
        <p>
            Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". 
        </p>
        <p>you can move any element and did't brak the stucture , it has many advantages and disadvantages too !!</p>
        <img src="pet.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" />
    </div>


    <div>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <h1>test</h1>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

if i could't explain my quesion in right way due to language constraint , i wish that the code snippet did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's normal behavior precisely because you don't have any `position:relative` in any of the parents so css uses the viewport height as reference.

If you add `body { position:relative}` it will be relative to the body and thus be at the bottom of the page.

If you add `.content { position:relative}` it will be in the bottom of the blue content box.

Comment: yeah , thanks for your declaration . this is one of my " aha moment " related to css as i imagined that this behavior would happen by default as they should interact with the page direct not viewport

Comment: Yep, `position:relative` was an "aha moment" for me as well. I'm with you - there are so many counter-intuitive things about css.